# How to stop reading when input is "q" in bash?

Tags: bash, input

I am using `read` for user input to perform some operation.  The selector uses a two character test to print the appropriate information, without requiring the user to press `ENTER` after his input.  Would it be possible to accept the `q` value to exit, because it is not composed of a two character selector.

```
  local done="false"
  while [ "$done" != "true" ]
  do
    echo ; read -n 2 lsk
    case $lsk in
     "1L")
        echo "$navaid_vscal"
        echo -e "$tacrgm"
        ;;
     q)
        done="true"  # ends while loop
        echo -n "$sgr"
        ;;
     *)
        ## repeats while do
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the bash `read` built-in has that functionality. However you can implement a custom read *command* or *function* to achieve that.

For example, you can use this function:

```bash
read_or_quit(){
x=0;
while ((++x<=2)); do 
   read -n 1

   if [[ $REPLY = q ]]; then 
      echo q
      break
   else 
     echo -n "$REPLY"
   fi
done ; 
echo

# I thought that printing `echo` to `stdout` would
# append a new line which might break the `case` 
# functionality.
# echo >&2
}
```

And you can call the function by using `$(read_or_quit)` in your code:

```bash
local done="false"
  while [ "$done" != "true" ]
  do
    lsk=$(read_or_quit)
    case $lsk in
     "1L")
        echo "$navaid_vscal"
        echo -e "$tacrgm"
        ;;
     q)
        done="true"  # ends while loop
        echo -n "$sgr"
        ;;
     *)
        ## repeats while do
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `echo >&2` ?

Comment: @konmi For printing a `break line` to `stderr`. It's not necessary at all, you can simply use `echo` or just remove it. I used `echo` at the end of the function to avoid using this one after you call the function: `lsk=$(read_or_quit)`.

Comment: What does it mean "to avoid using this one", what does "the one" refer to?

Comment: @konmi I meant `echo`, to avoid using `echo`. If you removed the `echo` a break line will not be printed. You can remove it and the code will work but the output might be ugly

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I would have to keep it, although printing to `stderr` seems unimportant in my case.  Why would you elect to send it to `stderr` ?

Comment: So looking closely, appending a new line to `stdout` does nto actually break the `case` clause ?

Comment: @konmi I've faced some problems when comparing strings because of the break line. So I thought that in this case using `echo` for printing to `stdout` would break the the `case` comparisons. So you can simply use `echo` and will work (I've tested it). I will be reading about this issue or hopefully someone resolves my doubt.

Comment: @konmi regarding `Why would you elect to send it to stderr?`. I've sent to `stderr` to avoid `lsk` variable has the value of `echo >&2`. For example, try using this: `echo Some string >&2` and test it in your code. You will notice that the code is still working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Split the read into an initial read (which leaves early when `q` is entered) and a subsequent one for the second character (I'll call them `ch1` and `ch2`):

```
local done=false
until "$done"
do
    echo
    read -n 1 ch1
    if [ ch1 = q ]
    then
        printf %s "$sgr"  # More portable than echo -n
        break
    fi
    read -n 1 ch2
    case "$ch1$ch2" in
        1L)
            echo "$navaid_vscal"
            echo -e "$tacrgm"  # portability problem here!
            ;;
        *)
            ## repeats while do
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Obviously, the loop can be `while true` since nothing now sets `done`, but perhaps you'll need that in one of the `case` blocks, so I kept it.  (I did change the string equality test to just running `$done` as a command, for simplicity)